# How to get a value of foreign key between apps of Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

If somebody has this kind of issue, answer is below, did it :)

I have two apps (accounts and company).

*accounts/models.py*

```
class Organization(models.Model):
      organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

#custom user model
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser):
      which_organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
      #other fields
```

*company/models.py*

```
from accounts import models as accounts_model

class Branch(models.Model):
          branch_name = models.ForeignKey(
          accounts_model.Organization, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
          #other fields
```

*company/forms.py*

```
from .models import Branch

class BranchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = '__all__'
```

*company/views.py*

```
from .forms import BranchForm

def some_function(request):
    form = BranchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = BranchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save(commit=False)
          form.branch_name = request.user.which_organization  
          print("User organization: ", request.user.which_organization)
          form.save()
    return render(request, 'company/index.html', {'form': form})
```

P.s. Everything works well. I am able to print the user's organization with
`print("User organization : ", request.user.which_organization)`
But cannot save it with
`form.branch_name = request.user.which_organization`
in views.py. Instead of getting exact organization name of the user, created object lists all organization names...

How to achieve it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it :D

```
def some_function(request):
    form = BranchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = BranchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          another_form = form.save(commit=False)
          another_form.branch_name =  Organisation.objects.get(id= request.user.which_organization.id )  
          new_form.save()
    return render(request, 'company/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Instead of retrieving organization data for a current user using a query. You can use ```request.user.which_organization```

Comment: I would like to add one more thing. Whenever importing models from another app in the same project better do this ```from app_name.models import ModelName```

Comment: Yeap, after I'va changed it to from app.model import model.

Comment: Retrieving an organization name using ```request.user.which_organization``` did the job when printing, but whenever save event occurs it was not saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing an instance of the Organisation model,

```
def some_function(request):
    form = BranchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = BranchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save(commit=False)
          organisation_instance = Organisation.objects.get(id = request.user.which_organization.id )  
          form.branch_name = organisation_instance  
          print("User organization: ", request.user.which_organization)
          form.save()
    return render(request, 'company/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! The same result again ;(

Comment: can you explain once again what you wanted and what is the issue that is being caused

Comment: I have an app called accounts and another one is company. 1. In accounts app I have created custom user model, which has as one of the fields which_organization ForeignKey field (connected with Organization model class in the same app, which contains only organization_name CharField). 2. In the company app's model I have just one model class named Branch, which contains branch_name(organization name I mean, which depends to this company) ForeignKey field(connected to custom user class in accounts app).

Comment: try printing out organisation_instance and organisation_instance.organization_name before form save in the console and check if the correct instance is being accessed

Comment: I want to save the User's organization name, which he belongs to into Branch model, that's it)

Comment: what is being printed in the console when you do this request.user.which_organization ?

Comment: Shows the exact organization name, which he/she belongs to)

Comment: I've tried printing organisation_instance and organisation_instance.organization_name, both shows the exact organization too. But when saving, there is still all organization names as drop down list.

Comment: do you mean dropdown list as in the admin panel ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238784/discussion-between-firdavsbek-narzullaev-and-sangeeth-subramoniam).